# How to make a backup with deja-dup from command line?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I have been using deja-dup GUI for quiet some time and I am very satisfied with it. However, I would also like to execute the same profile via command line. Is that possible?

In particular, I would like to make a backup on command line - either through deja-dup or duplicity - with the following setup:

```
Storage location
    Windows Share
    wdmycloud
    /USER/backup/deja-dup/T430s/
    NA
    NA
Folders to ignore
    NA
Folders to save
    ~/FOLDER1
    ~/FOLDER2
```

Answer (score 10):

[Déjà Dup](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DejaDup) is a GUI that uses `duplicity` as the back-end and hence there are only limited command-line options. You can run `man deja-dup` and see the various options available. For example to start a backup run:

> `deja-dup --backup`

or to restore a file `file`:

> `deja-dup --restore file`

(Note that these commands just invoke the GUI from terminal)

To get more powerful options from command-line you should consider installing [duplicity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DuplicityBackupHowto) which is strictly a CLI.

Comment: ok I see. can you please have a look on my edit? I am looking for a very concrete example on how to use deja-dup or duplicity.

Comment: Whatever the case may be if you want to avoid GUI, duplicity is the way to go. Have a look at the link above.