# Resetting but keeping last day's files

Tags: reset

im having a problem with my ubuntu. I made a disaster today and i'd like to reset it, but without clearing it at all, just resetting by 1/2 days.
How can i do that?
Thanks for your time

Comment: No.  Unless you explicitly set up some facility to do a periodic backup (as far as I know, one wouldn't be set automatically for you), you can't do what you're suggesting.  If you set it up, then presumably you would have known.

Comment: @Ray, that's a good *answer*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking like the `Time Machine` facility for MacOS, then no, it does not exist under Linux by default.  There are programs to do periodic backups and that fairly economical in terms of disk space.  For example, `timeshift` for system files or `rsnapshot` for personal files.  However, none of them (as far as I know) are set up automatically.  You would have to set them up yourself.

If you haven't set them up manually, then what you're asking for isn't possible.

Comment: or `duplicity` (it has a nice GUI: `Déjà Dup`). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/636264/how-to-make-a-backup-with-deja-dup-from-command-line